# How to create monit monitor to alert when a line of text is NOT seen in a log file over a period of time

Tags: monit

I can see how to alert when a regex appears in a log file.
I can see how to alert when a regex does not appear on EVERY line of a log file.
But I can't see how to alert when a regex has not appeared in a log file over a period of time.

I could create a bash script which regex's the file for me, and writes out to a file which monit monitors, but would rather keep the solution within monit.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

From the manual:

IF [NOT] MATCH {regex|path} [[]  CYCLES] THEN action

**The content is only being checked every cycle. If content is being added and removed between two checks they are unnoticed.**

Use the CYCLE option.  The limitation I see here is the cycles. The manual defaults to 300 seconds (5 minutes).  Determine how many cycles are needed and then tweak the alerting.

Comment: Thanks John.  I'll give it a go on my server and report back.

Comment: Not sure that this works John.  I entered the following:

Comment: check file system.log with path /var/log/system.log
  if NOT match "BLAH" within 2 cycles then alert
  group prices

Comment: This will alert on every line which does not match the pattern "BLAH".  Which is different to what I want to do.  I want to alert when I don't receive something over a period of time.

Comment: If that entry is not working I would then post to the monit mailing list and ask them.  Sorry if that didn't help.

Comment: Combine John's suggestion with the nagios [check_logs](http://exchange.nagios.org/directory/Plugins/Uncategorized/Operating-Systems/Linux/check_logs/details) script and you should be golden. There are multiple nrpe log plugins that you could utilize.